# Deploying 2 Spring Boot Microservices with React frontend in AWS with MySql db

Tags: mysql, reactjs, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, deployment

I'm currently trying to decide on the best/cheapest option for a small project. I have 2 microsevices (One for authentication, one for functionality), mysql db and a React Frontend.

I'll mainly be using it as learning just for myself so I don't need a load balancer or auto scaling.

I was thinking of deploying in Kubernetes but this may be an overkill.

Another option was refactoring and using Lambda but apparently it's not ideal for Spring Boot?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: My goal is to run the app for a month with not more than 200 calls a day.

Comment: You can write lambdas with Spring Boot.  Start up time is the issue to watch.  Keep your dependencies to a minimum and use Graal JVM if you can.  I would say K8S is very much overkill.  Lambda is best for 200 calls a day.  That's nothing.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to run the services on an EC2 instance that is eligible for a free tier. Ensure to shut down the EC2 instance so that you do not lose compute credits.
In case you need a larger instance, opt for a spot instance to keep the cost to a minimum.

Please note that you will be billed for storage even when the EC2 instances are turned off.